# NPM Install error Darwin

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

While trying todo a npm install I keep receiving the following error. Can someone help with this ? [image]

Comment: do you get error with all `npm packages` or only with `darwin` ?

Comment: Describe what are you trying to do and what command do you use?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` file ? It says clearly you don't.

Comment: @PashaRumkin I'm trying to do an npm install and then install bower

Comment: @Pogrindis I have a package.json file in the directory

Comment: Add additional info: your package.json file and listing of your directory.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that there is no `package.json` file in current directory. If it missed you should to create it with `npm init` command. If you try to install some package type it's name `npm install package-name`.